# WPF Emgu CV. Capture class cuts my video camera image(Mosaic)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, video-capture

Video frame looks like mozaik. 
What wrong with it and how can be fixed?

http://www.emgu.com

[image]

Is any other library that can show video with less processor resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like there's something wrong with the initial offset of the video data and/or the stride. Are you sure all parameters used in your code are correct? Never experienced something like that while using EmguCV (and just showing camera input). The blue borders on the left/right are some background/outside stuff I assume? Or is the whole picture your camera image?

Comment: Yes, blue borders just background.I set resolution to capture object. Default camera resolution was small and without any bugs.

Comment: Maybe the selected resolution isn't supported by your cam? Try some default resolutions like 320x240 or 640x480.

Comment: Error with 640x480. I will try other hi res. camera.